# Implementing Levenshtein distance in python

Tags: python, levenshtein-distance

I have implemented the algorithm, but now I want to find the edit distance for the string which has the shortest edit distance to the others strings.

Here is the algorithm:

```
def lev(s1, s2):
    return min(lev(a[1:], b[1:])+(a[0] != b[0]), lev(a[1:], b)+1, lev(a, b[1:])+1)
```

Comment: Is that lev function right? a and b are not defined, and if you meant for the args to be a and b, it runs over the recursion limit.

Answer (score 5):

Your "implementation" has several flaws:

(1) It should start with `def lev(a, b):`, not `def lev(s1, s2):`. Please get into the good habits of (a) running your code before asking questions about it (b) quoting the code that you've actually run (by copy/paste, not by (error-prone) re-typing).

(2) It has no termination conditions; for any arguments it will eventually end up trying to evaluate `lev("", "")` which would loop forever were it not for Python implementation limits: `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`.

You need to insert two lines:

```
if not a: return len(b)
if not b: return len(a)
```

to make it work.

(3) The Levenshtein distance is *defined* recursively. There is no such thing as "the" (one and only) algorithm. Recursive code is rarely seen outside a classroom and then only in a "strawman" capacity.

(4) Naive implementations take time and memory proportional to `len(a) * len(b)` ... aren't those strings normally a little bit longer than 4 to 8?

(5) Your extremely naive implementation is worse, because it copies slices of its inputs.

You can find *working* not-very-naive implementations on the web ... google("levenshtein python") ... look for ones which use `O(max(len(a), len(b)))` additional memory.

What you asked for ("the edit distance for the string who has the shortest edit distance to the others strings.") Doesn't make sense ... "THE string"??? "It takes two to tango" :-)

What you probably want (finding all pairs of strings in a collection which have the minimal distance), or maybe just that minimal distance, is a simple programming exercise. What have you tried?

By the way, finding those pairs by a simplistic algorithm will take O(N ** 2) executions of `lev()` where N is the number of strings in the collection ... if this is a real-world application, you should look to use proven code rather than try to write it yourself. If this is homework, you should say so.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're looking for ??

```
import itertools
import collections

# My Simple implementation of Levenshtein distance
def levenshtein_distance(string1, string2):
    """
    >>> levenshtein_distance('AATZ', 'AAAZ')
    1
    >>> levenshtein_distance('AATZZZ', 'AAAZ')
    3
    """

    distance = 0

    if len(string1) < len(string2):
        string1, string2 = string2, string1

    for i, v in itertools.izip_longest(string1, string2, fillvalue='-'):
        if i != v:
            distance += 1
    return distance

# Find the string with the shortest edit distance.
list_of_string = ['AATC', 'TAGCGATC', 'ATCGAT']

strings_distances = collections.defaultdict(int)

for strings in itertools.combinations(list_of_string, 2):
    strings_distances[strings[0]] += levenshtein_distance(*strings)
    strings_distances[strings[1]] += levenshtein_distance(*strings)

shortest = min(strings_distances.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Comment: This is wrong: levenshtein_distance("ABCDEFGH", "AABCDEFGH") returns 8, when it should be 1 (insert 'A')

Comment: @luispedro: actually i know and like i said in my answer __My Simple implementation of Levenshtein distance__, i write this __Simple Implementation__ just to show him the second part of my answer which is what the OP  ask for : __getting the string who has the shortest edit distance to the others strings__ , and because the algo that he put don't work :)

Comment: This is great, but how can I write it without the use of itertools and collections?

Comment: @Karl Grims: is this a homework ? because it sound from your question that it's , fortunately if it's a homework i can't give you all the answer, but i think you have all the clue in the answers that you got , so you can figure this out yes !! :)

Comment: @singularity: You're welcome :-) It should be about -10  ... all you need is `min(lev(*pair) for pair in itertools.combinations(the_list, 2))`

Comment: @John Machin: i just added a -1 to my answer(ooops is not possible :) ) so i don't even forget it, and thank you for reminding me that i have to learn more and more :)